# Where can I see the logs from background-script?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am developing my first add-on in Firefox. I could manage to use correctly content scripts and scripts inside a window I create from the popup — the one triggered by the browser-action button.
Now I would like to use a script in background and I have a simple question:

> When I write a statement such as :

```
console.log("Hi I am the background script!");
```

> where can I see the result?

In other words, how to see what is happening in the background script?
I have tried many consoles but nowhere I could see the greeting message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually found the answer. To open the console for background script, go to the page **about:debugging**. Once the addon is installed, click the **inspect** button. A new tab containing the console is opened.